# Formik input value for a number becomes a string even after it passes the Formik validation as a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik

I have an input through `Formik` that takes in number, but even when it passes the `Formik` validation, the resulting input is still categorized as `string`.

```js
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{ price: '' }}
                    onSubmit={submitHandler}
                    validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
                    price: yup
                        .number()
                        .required(),
                    })}
                >
                    {({ values, handleChange, errors, setFieldTouched, touched, isValid, handleSubmit }) => (
                        <View style={styles.form}>
                            <View style={styles.fieldset}>
                                <Text style={{ marginLeft: 40, marginVertical: 10 }}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: '#FF5D4E'}}>* </Text>
                                    Price
                                </Text>
                                <TextInput
                                    value={values.price}
                                    keyboardType = 'numeric'
                                    onChangeText={handleChange('price')}
                                    placeholder="Rental price of your item per day"
                                    style={styles.textInput}
                                    onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('price')}
                                />
                            </View>
                            {touched.price && errors.price &&
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.price}</Text>
                            }

                            <TouchableOpacity
                                disabled={!isValid || loading}
                                onPress={handleSubmit}
                                style={styles.button}
                            >
                                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity> 
                        </View> 
                    )}
                </Formik>
```

When the price is entered, any non-number is met with a warning. However, when I console log the the value passed to the `submitHandler` function, the `typeof` shows the price value as a string.

Comment: I've never use yup, but in joi just using number() doesn't control the type but only the content. Try adding .strict() to the validation

Comment: @Auticcat What's the difference between the type and content?

Comment: For example number = 1 has content equal to 1 but has as type number. If you do number = “1” has content equal to 1 like before, but is a string. Doing strict will control that the content is a number but also control that the type is equal to number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse the `string` value in `onChangeText` like this:

```
{({ values, ...., setFieldValue }) => {

// parse string value to int
const parseAndHandleChange = (value, setFieldValue, id) => {
      const parsed = parseInt(value, 10)
      setFieldValue(id, parsed)
    }

return (
 <View>
 {.....}
 <TextInput
   value={values.price}
   keyboardType = 'numeric'
   onChangeText={value => parseAndHandleChange(value, setFieldValue, 'price')}
   placeholder="Rental price of your item per day"
   style={styles.textInput}
   onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('price')}
 />
 </View>
)}
```

This is just an example, feel free to modify based on your use case. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

This is just happening while using Formik with React Native. In React for web you can set the input with `type="number"` but in React Native you can't.

Even if you add `keyboardType="numeric"` to `<TextInput />`. In the other hand, if you use Yup (which I strongly recommend) this is not checking for type, just for content this means `"1"` may be interpreted as a number.

Solution:

```
import Formik from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';

...

<Formik 
  initialValues={{ price: '' }}
  validationSchema={yup.object().shape({ price: yup.number() })}
/>
{(values, setFieldValue, handleBlur) => (
  <TextInput 
    value={values.price} 
    onChangeText={value => setFieldValue('price', parseFloat(value))}
    onBlur={handleBlur('price')}
    keyboardType="decimal-pad"
  />
)}
</Formik>
```

happy coding!

Comment: is this what you're referring to? https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/48ac4c38688a1570a7e4f05522164df6cb54bcd0/src/number.js#L26

Comment: it looks like Yup converts string into number through `parseInt` to check for things like min() or max() so '1' would turn into 1 as you said

Comment: `type='number'` also worked for me. Without this, despite being bound to property of type number it still was a string.